# How do i route to public folder JS and CSS files instead of sub-directories in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, rails-routing

I am working on a rails project where I have multiple users. I have used the standard architecture to create multiple users. I am trying not to use the asset pipeline for now for rendering CSS and JS files.

By default, on my homepage, when i include a JS or CSS file, it automatically looks in the public folder in my rails project folder. for example:

html.erb file 'include tags':

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/default.css">
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/default.js"></script>
```

These 2 lines of code now look for the 'public/css/defaults.css' and 'public/js/default.js' respectively.

However, when I SHOW a single user, now the url path changes to for example: www.mywebsite.com/user/13

As a result, now the same 2 include tags for CSS and JS now point to 'public/user/css/defaults.css' and 'public/user/js/defaults.js'. I am having to duplicate the JS and CSS files in a public/user directory for the CSS and JS to be included in the user-show pages.

Is there a way to route the include tags back to the 'public' folder instead of the 'public/user' folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try including a '/' for root?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/default.css">
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/js/default.js"></script>
```